# Drop event not firing in dynamic list - Svelte

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, svelte

I have a dynamic list of contenteditables rendered in Svelte and want to be able to drag them to resort them but on:drop or on:dragover both don't seem to be firing. I was thinking it was because it thinks I am trying to drop it on the children elements but if I move those events to a child it still doesn't fire or show the correct cursor.

```html
<div
  on:dragover|preventDefault={handleDragOver}
  on:dragenter|preventDefault={handleDragEnter}
  on:drop={handleDrop}
>
  <div
    on:dragstart={handleDragStart}
    on:dragend={handleDragEnd}
    draggable="true"
  >
    /* Child div here that looks like list bullet (where I want the user to hover to begin dragging */
    /* contenteditable div here */
  </div>
</div>
```

There is nothing actually happening in the functions each event is calling except a console.log() to see if it is firing. The events on the draggable div fire fine, but on the parent div I want it to drop to no events are fired. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems to be working fine in the Repl? https://svelte.dev/repl/7e425d4a92874d75874a496f5cc3b6a6?version=3.56.0

Comment: Hmm, thanks for checkng that. I'm actually running it through Tauri so maybe that is messing with it somehow, I'll have to check to see if there are similar problems later today

Comment: It was Tauri, I needed to set fileDropEnabled to false in the tauri config

Answer (score 1):

The problem in this case was Tauri. I needed to set fileDropEnabled to false in tauri.conf.json under "windows".